# Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show series convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Firstly we are given that $a_k\in\mathbb C$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty {a_k}^2$ converges absolutely. The question then asks to show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}$ converges absolutely.

I know that absolute convergence of the first series this implies that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty ||{a_k}^2||$ converges.

Thus by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality I get

$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty ||{a_k}^2|| \leq \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty ||{a_k}||.||a_k||
$$

From this point onwards I have no idea of how to proceed. (Should I make use of Cauchy products?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{k} \leq \sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k^2\right ) \left ( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} \right ) }$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: should there be a square root on the right hand side?

Comment: Yeah, I'll fix it

Comment: @Jeb So from this, can you just conclude that for the RHS, since the term on the left converges absolutely and the term to the right of that converges, that LHS converges absolutely? Or would more have to be said?

Comment: Since everything on the RHS converges, we know it is finite. This implies that the sum on the LHS side is finite. Therefore it convergeces absolutely.