# Jay Cummings real analysis, question 4.14 - can be proved without Cauchy-Shwartz?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Here is the question:**
Prove that if $a_k>0$ for all k and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k}^2$ converges, then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{k}$ converges.

There is an already existing answer in this forum which provides a solution using Cauchy-Shwartz - [Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show series convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809980/use-cauchy-schwarz-inequality-to-show-series-convergence)

However, I am asking a different question. My understanding is that the questions in the book can be solved using the knowledge acquired from the book **so far**. Therefore I am curious whether this question can be solved **without** Cauchy-Shwartz.

Here is what I currently have in terms of trying to solve it.

Suppose $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k^2 \ge (a_k - \frac{1}{k})^2$ $\forall k \ge n$. In that case, we have something like this:
$$
a_k^2 \ge (a_k - \frac{1}{k})^2 \\
a_k^2 \ge a_k^2 + \frac{1}{k^2} - \frac{2a_k}{k} \\
a_k \ge \frac{1}{2k}
$$
And also:
$$
L = \sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}{a_k}^2 \ge \sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}(a_k - \frac{1}{k})^2 > 0
$$
Therefore if $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k \ge \frac{1}{2k}$ $\forall k \ge n$, then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(a_k - \frac{1}{k})^2$ converges. But then $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{k}$ must converge as well.

There is only one tiny problem with my reasoning - I have no idea how to prove that my initial assumption ($\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_k \ge \frac{1}{2k}$ $\forall k \ge n$) is true OR what to do if it is false.

**EDIT 1**

The assumption can be improved like this:
$$
\exists m,n \in \mathbb{N} : a_k \ge \frac{1}{2mk} \forall k \ge n
$$
In that case $a_k^2 \ge (a_k - \frac{1}{mk})^2$ and it would still follow that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{k}$ must converge.

But again, I do not know how to prove this improved assumption or what to do if it is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use, that if series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^{2}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}^{2}$ converged, then also converged $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}b_{n}|\quad(1)$

This can be obtained from inequality $|a_{n}b_{n}|\leqslant \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}^{2}+b_{n}^{2})$.

Now, using $(1)$, and take $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$, we obtain desired convergence of$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}$  .

Comment: So cool and so simple.

Comment: One question, though. Why do you need to take the absolute value in inequality expression?

Comment: Perhaps this is a habit or craving to write an expression in the most accurate or general form. $(1)$ works with any series.